# awk - show difference between two fields

Tags: awk, gawk

I have this:

```
bar foobar        
111 random111
```

I want to define $2 so that when compared to $1, it should contain only the differences (non-matching characters):

```
bar foo
111 random
```

Comment: Shouldn't your second column contain `foo` and `random`? How is your output showing differences?

Comment: What if $1 contained an RE metacharacter (`.`, `+`, `?`, `*`, etc.)? Would you want it to be taken as that literal character or to perform it's RE function? What if the `$1` contained `o` and $2 `foo` - should the output be `fo` or `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the differences as jaypal points out:

```
awk '{gsub($1,"",$2)}1' file
bar foo
111 random
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest things elude me. Thanks.